# Get data from external book with named range to a named range

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Good morning all,

I have rather limited vba experience but can generally adjust 'googled' code to fit most of my basic needs.
However, I am currently having an issue with the below code. The intention is to grab data from a table in one sheet and replicate it in an equally sized table (both called named range - MainList) on another sheet.

It works fine for individual cells but does not want to do the whole range. Can anybody help?

```
Dim path As String
path = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

Dim currentWb As Workbook
Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim openWb As Workbook
Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim openWs As Worksheet
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Job Details")

currentWb.Sheets("Main List").Range("MainList") = openWs.Range("MainList")

openWb.Close (False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Copy and Paste

```
Dim openWb As Workbook
Dim openWs As Worksheet
Dim openRange As Range
Dim destRange As Range

Set openWb = Workbooks.Open("E:\DOCS\Book1.xlsm")
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set openRange = openWs.Range("$A$1:$H$16")
Set destRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$H$16")

'magic happens here
openRange.Copy
destRange.PasteSpecial

openWb.Close False

Set openWs = Nothing
Set openWb = Nothing
```

Comment: Sorry for the slightly late reply but that was perfect! Thanks so much for your prompt reply - greatly appreciated

Comment: Actually, I've tried replicating this formula for a different job and where the range includes images these are not copied. I've tried loads of things like xlPasteAll but can't get it to work. Any ideas?